# How can I return text with color angular based on value

Tags: angular

I want to change the name and add a diferent color to my text depends on the value. I have this function
it's return the text but I also want to add a color for each text.

```
  getEstado(data) {
    switch (data) {

      case 1:
        return '<li>Aprobado</li>';
        
        break;
      case 2:
        return  '<li>Negado</li>';
        break;
      case 3:
        return '<li>Suspendido</li>';
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
    
  }
```

I call the function here

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columns = [
       
        {
            header: "Estatus",
            field:"estado",
            width: "150px",
            formatter: (data) => this.getEstado(data.estado), 
           
        }
       
    ];
    this.getData();
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `class` for each color and add the classes based on the condition in your function:

```
getEstado(data) {
  switch (data) {

    case 1:
      return '<li class="text-danger">Aprobado</li>';
    
      break;
    case 2:
      return  '<li class="text-success">Negado</li>';
      break;
    case 3:
      return '<li class="text-warning">Suspendido</li>';
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

}
```

Then you can add color to the classes in css:

```
.text-danger {
  color: red;
}

.text-success{
  color: green;
}
.text-warning{
  color: yellow;
}
```